# how to make ascending and descending with selection sort python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, selection-sort

I have a list

```
listA = [150, 120, 100, 165, 190, 145, 182, 175, 17]
```

I need it to be sorted in ascending and descending order (selection sort), like this

```
Ascending
[17, 100, 120, 145, 150, 165, 175, 190]
Descending
[190, 175, 165, 150, 145, 120,100, 17]
```

I have seen and try few times but still fail. Most of the case have this kinda solving way

```
for i in range(len(listA)-1):
      for i in range(len(listA)-1):
            if (listA[i]>listA[i+1]):
                listA[i],listA[i+1]=listA[i+1],listA[i]
```

But that's just can do ascending order/descending (one of them), is there another way to get ascending and descending  data in the same program?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `sorted` built-in function? Either way, you'd have to run it twice, once for ascending, and once for descending. You could just send them to new lists.

Comment: I have seen sorted build-in, but this task should be done with if else statement, Could you give me code example or reference, im not really good at coding?

Comment: See the duplicate, there are approaches in there that do not use the built in sort

Comment: Use a `ascending=True` variable, and inside the two loops check that: if it's true, do the logic you have in the loop, if it's false, do the reverse `if listA[i] < listA[i + 1]:`

Answer (score 1):

You can sort a list with `listA.sort()` method.
If you want it to be reversed you can sort it with the flag `reverse=True`.

Comment: Is there another way, i have to solve it with if else statement, i'm really new to programming

Comment: You can create your own sort, depends on ascending or descending order.

Comment: You can create your own sort, depends on ascending or descending order.
I'll demonstrate it for ascending order:
```
sorted_list = []
for i in range(len(listA)):
    max_val = max(listA)
    sorted_list.insert(0, max_val)
    listA.remove(max_val)
```